# Prove or disprove: $(A\setminus B) \times C = (A\times B)\setminus (B \times C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

> Prove or disprove: $$(A\setminus B) \times C = (A\times B)\setminus (B \times C).$$

If  we look at the left side of the statment, $(A\setminus B) \times C$, we can say that we have $\{a,b\}$ where $a$ belongs to $A$ only and $b$ belong to $C$ (by the defenition of Cartesian product).

But if we look at the right side, $(A\times B)\setminus (B \times C)$, we can say that we have $\{a,b\}$ where $a$ belong to $A$ but not $B$ and $b$ belong to $B$ but not $C$ .

the problem is that $y$ cant be belong to $C$ on the one hand and on the other hand not belong to $C$? Or am i mistaken ?

Please help. If it's really not true I need a counterexample.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What has this got to do with [tag:group-theory]?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What does the right-hand side mean?  What does it mean to juxtapose two sets?  If $X,Y$ are sets, what is $XY$?

Comment: @Shaun A ,B ,C are groups and this is discrete mathematics prove or refute

Comment: @saulspatz I edited the question is it better to understand?

Comment: Are you sure that what you want to prove or disprove is $(A\setminus B)\times C=(A\times C)\setminus (B\times C)$, rather than what you’ve written?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin no .. i need to frove or disprove what i wrote in the quetion

Comment: What you wrote in the question does not even make sense. What does “$(A\times B)(B\times C)$” even mean? There is no set-theoretic operator between the two sets, so what you wrote is just *nonsense*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes , (A x B) \ (B x C)

Comment: @Shaun is the title better ?

Comment: A little bit, yeah. But are you sure you mean "group" and not "set"?

Comment: @Shaun yes . im sorry im not american so its a bit hard for me , ill change it to set theory

Comment: Yes, that's much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A=B=\{x\}, C=\varnothing$. Then $A\setminus B=\varnothing,$ so

$$\begin{align}
(A\setminus B)\times C&=\varnothing\times\varnothing\\
&=\varnothing.
\end{align}$$

But $A\times B=\{(x,x)\}$ and

$$\begin{align}
B\times C&=\{(b, c)\mid b\in B\land c\in C\}\\
&=\varnothing,
\end{align}$$

so $$(A\times B)\setminus (B\times C)=\{(x, x)\},$$ which is nonempty.